# Why do some superconductors have a large $λ$ but a low $T_c$? Is it because mass renormalization dominates in these systems?

Tags: temperature, renormalization, superconductivity

We know some [superconductors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconductivity) have a large λ, but a low $T_c$. Some have a small λ but a high $T_c$. Why are they different? From the [Eliashberg equations](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aop.2020.168102), we know the [renormalization function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization) is associated with the λ and $T_c$. Is it because λ contributes to mass renormalization in systems with large λ low $T_c$?

How does it take action?

Is there some quantity I can calculate to evaluate it? I would like to get some references about this question.